# Enable button in the same row when checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to activate the button based on the checked id. in the picture below, the enable button does not match the checked id
[image: in the picture below, the enable button does not match the checked id]

View:

```
@forelse ($category as $ctg)
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="kategori_checkbox" value="{{ $ctg->id }}">
      </td>
      <td>{{ $ctg->kode_kategori }}</td>
      <td>{{ $ctg->nama_kategori }}</td>
      <td>
        <a href="{{ url('data-kategori/restore/'.$ctg->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm disabled btn-aksi">
          <i class="fa fa-undo"> Restore</i>
        </a>
        <a href="{{ url('data-kategori/delete/'.$ctg->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm disabled btn-aksi">
          <i class="fa fa-trash"> Delete</i>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
@empty
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" class="text-center" style="font-weight: bold; background-color:rgb(236, 236, 236)">Data Kosong</td>
    </tr>
@endforelse
```

JavaScript:

```
//REMOVE DISABLED CLASS BTN AKSI WHEN KATEGORI ID CHECKED
$(document).on('click','input[name="kategori_checkbox"]', function(){
  if($('input[name="kategori_checkbox"]:checked').length == 1){
    $('.btn-aksi').removeClass('disabled');
  }else{
    $('.btn-aksi').addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In:

```js
$(document).on('click','input[name="kategori_checkbox"]', function(){
  if($('input[name="kategori_checkbox"]:checked').length == 1){
    $('.btn-aksi').removeClass('disabled');
  }else{
    $('.btn-aksi').addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

More specifically in

```
if($('input[name="kategori_checkbox"]:checked').length == 1){
```

You are selecting *all* `input`s in the document. Later on the next line, similarly, when you do

```
$('.btn-aksi').removeClass('disabled');
```

you are also selecting all elements with a `btn-aksi` class (not just those close to the checked box.

**The fix:** What you want, instead is to select the `input` and the `.btn-aksi` only of the clicked line.

For that you can (1) use `$(this)` to select the clicked checkbox, (2) use [`.closest('tr')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to navigate to its parent `<tr>` and from there you can select all `.btn-aksi` via [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

```js
$(document).on('click','input[name="kategori_checkbox"]', function(){
  const checkbox = $(this);
  if(checkbox.is(':checked')){
    checkbox.closest('tr').find('.btn-aksi').removeClass('disabled');
  }else{
    checkbox.closest('tr').find('.btn-aksi').addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

Demo:

```js
$(document).on('click','input[name="kategori_checkbox"]', function(){
  const checkbox = $(this);
  if(checkbox.is(':checked')){
    checkbox.closest('tr').find('.btn-aksi').removeClass('disabled');
  }else{
    checkbox.closest('tr').find('.btn-aksi').addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}

a:not(.disabled) {
  color: green;
}
a.disabled {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="kategori_checkbox" value="{{ $ctg->id }}">
    </td>
    <td>kode_kategori</td>
    <td>nama_kategori</td>
    <td>
      <a href="{{ url('data-kategori/restore/'.$ctg->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm disabled btn-aksi">
        <i class="fa fa-undo"> Restore</i>
      </a>
      <a href="{{ url('data-kategori/delete/'.$ctg->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm disabled btn-aksi">
        <i class="fa fa-trash"> Delete</i>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="kategori_checkbox" value="{{ $ctg->id }}">
    </td>
    <td>kode_kategori</td>
    <td>nama_kategori</td>
    <td>
      <a href="{{ url('data-kategori/restore/'.$ctg->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm disabled btn-aksi">
        <i class="fa fa-undo"> Restore</i>
      </a>
      <a href="{{ url('data-kategori/delete/'.$ctg->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm disabled btn-aksi">
        <i class="fa fa-trash"> Delete</i>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```